# Is cloning illegal in the Star Trek: TNG continuity?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The few instances of clones being used in the *Star Trek* series have been seen to have usually negative implications.  And the artificial heart used to replace Picard's original organ (which was injured in a bar fight while he was in Star Fleet Academy decades before) is a bionic organ which seems to be what he still has been using well into his captaincy.

This raises the question as to why a new biological organ wasn't replicated. It *could* be that the bionic organs were simply seen as more efficient... but I suspect it may be possible that cloning organs alone may be frowned upon, let alone cloning a whole person. This may at least be the case within the Federation.

Is there any information to confirm this?

Comment: There's really no good evidence that the *Federation* frown on cloning per se. Individuals like Riker don't seem to like it on a personal basis; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Clone

Comment: @Valorum: ironic since [he was cloned](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Riker), kind of.

Comment: @Valorum That was a transporter accident, though, not really "Cloning".  But it does highlight the point: if the Federation has no real issue with it, why don't we see it done for medical procedures or more spoken off? The only civilization I saw that it was heavily used in was the one that tried to steal Riker and Dr. Polasky's DNA. The crew seemed to respect their culture, but it was inferred that this was still seen as a less than ideal form of continuance for a species/people.

Comment: @RussRainford While cloning per se might be ok, making clones to harvest them for organs probably is ethically reprehensible as the clones will be sentient beings. Cloning organs on the other hand should be ok, but it's never discussed as far as I remember.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum That's exactly what I mean, though! Using a tissue or DNA sample to clone or regrow an organ shouldn't be a major issue, but it makes little sense [unless the tech organs  are simply better]. So why then [plot contrivance aside] would a mechanical heart be more used, instead of just "growing him" a new one?

Comment: Legal aspects are never touched on, but based on the episode "Up the Long Ladder", there seem to be moral objections to harvesting genetic material for the purpose of (full body) cloning (and performed against the donor's will seems rather like assault in any universe), but there also seems to be a universal "ick" factor about it. Of course the Mariposans didn't seem to have any legal or moral qualms about what they were doing.

Comment: While regrowing an organ shouldn't be a major issue, it takes **time** to grow a new organ, and they presumably have an inventory of bionic parts ready to go in place of traumatic injury.

Comment: In the specific case of cloning new organs, they don't need to - TNG-era Starfleet could [replicate new organs from scratch](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genetronic_replicator). It was an experimental process (and wasn't around when Picard needed a new heart).

Comment: They used some form of organ cloning to replace Worf's entire spine at one point, so obviously they're okay with that.  (Although Worf himself took some convincing.)

Comment: @AnthonyX I can understand the legal aspect of "taking tissue against a person's will", as well as the moral issue. In the _Voyager_ episode "Phage", the Vidiian race used their advanced medical science to harvest organs from other species and put them into their bodies to slow a degenerative disease; this was often done against the other's species will. As a valid medical procedure, though, cloning tissue for a case like Picard's or WOrf's spinal injury, I can't see that as being invalid or anymore "icky" than a skin graft from ones own body.

Comment: @RonJohn I could see the time factor as an issue as well, but we've seen replicators recreate complete items in seconds, even whole _people_ from transport accidents. The ease of access and excess of bionic parts do make more sense, though, but again: the bionics could then be a stop gap, while the organics are grown and later inserted. So the lack of use of this technology to rebuild natural tissue still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Excellent point.  Remember, though, that artificial hearts were a Big Thing in the 1980s when the story was written.

Comment: @RonJohn A fair point yourself, my friend. We sometimes forget that the stories of a franchise like Star Trek are often very much influenced by the happenings of the time they are written. It just felt very _unlike_ Jean Luc to me that, after his bionic heart malfunctioned, that he wouldn't have a replacement one grown from his own body cells.... unless of course the tech heart gave him some advantage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Bajor is a (potential) member of the Federation. Ibudan, a Bajora, makes a clone in his quarters. Sisko and Bashir don't seem to have any problem with this whatsoever, nor do they seem intent on charging him with 'Felony Clonemaking' along with his murder rap.

> **ODO:** (re: the new clone) *What happens to this one?*
>
> **BASHIR:** *In about two days, he becomes a living, breathing member of Bajoran society.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: A Man Alone](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Man_Alone_(episode))</sup></sub>

The Federation is comprised of lots of planets, all with their own laws. From what I can recall, nobody ever raises a complaint about clones or cloning *per se*, only that they personally don't want to be cloned (as in *TNG: Up the Long Ladder*). Similarly, an incomplete clone doesn't appear to have any legal rights until it's activated, but once it gains consciousness it has all the rights of a Federation (or in this case, Bajoran) citizen.

Comment: Also the entire crew of Voyager agreed to be sort-of-cloned in [VOY: Demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)).

Comment: Don't forget [ENT: Similitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similitude_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)) too - which deals with the issue of cloning a replacement organ **donor**...

Comment: *Up the Long Ladder* makes it clear it's about consent: Riker and Pulaski did not volunteer their tissue to be used to create clones. Also note that Thomas Riker doesn't have any issues being a clone of Will (or vice-versa, or whatever), albeit one created via nonbiological means.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Thomas Riker doesn't have *legal* issues. He definitely has *issues*, given his eventual fate.

Comment: Bajor is *not* a member of the Federation during the events of *A Man Alone*, so Federation law is irrelevant. Bashir is, and no doubt has his own opinions about cloning quite separate from its legal status (possibly related to his being the product of Federation-illegal genetic manipulation), but he doesn't express an opinion one way or the other, presumably because it wouldn't be professional.

Comment: @RossThompson - Given that Bajor is applying for Federation membership, them breaking a Federation-wide law would be a huge deal. It most certainly is relevant to the discussion, not least because of Bashir's total lack of concern

Comment: Yeah, most planets are harmonizing to EU-I mean Federation law.  Except for Texas, obviously.